# NSArray persistence

Tags: objective-c, ios, amazon-web-services, persistence

I know this question was asked many times, but I've tried all the answers I could find, but that havent fixed my problem.

I have NSArray of Amazon cloud buckets. They need to be saved inside a file. 
First thing Ive done was try NSUserDefaults and that does not work:

```
-[NSUserDefaults setObject:forKey:]: Attempt to insert non-property value
```

The other thing I've tried is to encode it:

```
[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:array];
```

but I get:

```
-[S3Bucket encodeWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

Please help

Comment: I suspect your problems are not with the array per se but either with storage management, or with file path name stuff.  Verify that the array exists just before you write it and immediately after you read it, and verify that you can write/read a simple NSString using the same file path.

Comment: I think this link will help you

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1659922/converting-a-nsobject-into-nsdata

Comment: I think this link will help you

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1659922/converting-a-nsobject-into-nsdata][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1659922/converting-a-nsobject-into-nsdata

Answer (score 0):

you can use NSArray object to write the array to disk using

```
- (BOOL)writeToFile:(NSString *)path atomically:(BOOL)flag
```

and read it back in with:

```
- (id)initWithContentsOfFile:(NSString *)aPath
```

or

```
+ (id)arrayWithContentsOfFile:(NSString *)aPath
```

For Sample [follow this](http://mobiledevelopertips.com/data-file-management/read-and-write-array-dictionary-and-other-collections-to-files.html) link

Comment: `NSArray *bucketNames = [[AmazonClientManager s3] listBuckets];`

`[bucketNames writeToFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@bucketList", NSTemporaryDirectory()] atomically:YES];`

`NSArray *newNames = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@bucketList", NSTemporaryDirectory()]];`

`NSLog(@"%@", newNames);` 

returns null

Comment: try this: NSArray *bucketNames = [[AmazonClientManager s3] listBuckets]; [bucketNames writeToFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/bucketList.plist", NSTemporaryDirectory()] atomically:YES]; NSArray *newNames = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/bucketList.plist", NSTemporaryDirectory()]]; NSLog(@"%@", newNames)

Comment: http://mobiledevelopertips.com/data-file-management/read-and-write-array-dictionary-and-other-collections-to-files.html

Comment: Tried that returns null again.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15653/discussion-between-prince-and-andrius-steponavicius)