# Core Data and Arrays

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsmutablearray

I need to store these values.

x-value = time

y-value1, y-value2, y-value3, ... , y-value10

So for each time, there are these different yValue slices. That is the association between the two.

I am fairly new to Core-Data methodology and I have heard that storing them into arrays are not possible. I do not have to query them, but I do need to store them afterwards in the database after a given session (assume over 1000 of entires -- this is why I don't want to put them all in a NSMutableArray at first).

Is Core-Data the most practical way to attack this problem or is there a better solution to handle such amounts of data.

EDIT:
So far my model looks like this.

---

Entity 1: Timeslice

Attribute: time - float

Relationship: Values

---

Entity 2: Values

Attribute: yValue1, yValue2, yValue3, ..., yValue10 - float

Comment: You should show a bit more code plus your model. Otherwise this is rather guessing than answering. However, I guess that you should store your array values in a separate table and refer to the members of the array with a one-to-many relation.

Comment: Please check my edit. I haven't coded this up yet, but I was just wondering if I am heading in the right direction in terms of arrays in core-data.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what type of variable each yValue represents but it looks like you are probably going about it in a more awkward way than you need to. You can put them in an array and then store that array in an NSData attribute in the Core Data persistent store. If you really don't need to query them then I would make sure the yValue class implements the encodeWithCoder: method as detailed in this question: [Converting a NSObject into NSData](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1659922/converting-a-nsobject-into-nsdata)

You can then create an array of these objects and archive the whole array in an NSData object and store that in a single attribute of your entity. This would probably be the most efficient way to store it. Your core data model would then look like this:

Entity - Time Entry

Attribute: time - NSNumber

Attribute: yValues - NSData

Using this core data model you can query for a particular time (or set of times) and then unarchive the NSData objects as needed.

Relationships are better if you are going to create a 'type' of object. One classic example is the company->manager->employee paradigm. Each company, manager and employee would be an entity. There would be a to-many relationship from company to a number of managers and from each manager to a number of employees. You could also have each employee assigned to more than one manager, etc. etc.

Answer (score 0):

Core Data supports ordered relationships, I think from iOS5 onward.  Just select "ordered" in the checkbox when editing a to-many relationship.