# iOS CoreData - Serialize entire object instead of creating Entity

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I am working on an email client and I want to persist emails into CoreData.

Looking at some tutorials, it seems I need to create a custom class (entity) and add attributes for each field I want to persist.

The problem is that I have an array of pretty complex objects (http://libmailcore.com/mailcore2/api/Classes/MCOIMAPMessage.html) I want to serialize and persist. Is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: Please update your question detailing what you feel is hard/difficult about this.

Answer (score 1):

Try converting the MCOIMAPMessage to NSData and then you can persist it to coredata. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3749695/334091) SO post on how to convert NSObject to NSData. Hope this helps.